# viewing auto-added constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

This is a sentence from a book I'm reading:

If a view is affected by no constraints at all, it is given constraints tagged in the debugger as "IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame".

However, when I run a program with only a label in the main view (and I add no constraints at all) my output in Debugger area is completely empty. So where can I see the auto-added constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer. Went to Debug->View Debugging->Capture View Hierarchy.